# Open Source tool to construct ETL parser

Tags: open-source, software-development, java, business-intelligence

I need to create ETL parser in Java. Is there any opensource tool or framework available to build ETL parser for unstructured  data.

I want to create a parser and need to define format in properties file and parser must able to parse according to format in properties file.

I am not asking for full code.Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "ETL". ETL as in "Extract", "Transfer", "Load"?

Comment: Excatly, Extract Transfer Load..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build simple and complex Etl processes I recommend Kettle. Currently named Pentaho Data Integration. Written in Java with nice GUI and easy to integrate in Java software. Source available.  See [website](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/).

Comment: I asked in opensource..itseems kettle is not open source..!

Comment: See http://community.pentaho.com/faq/general.php and http://oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/apache2. In my vision the Apache License v2 is open source. What do you need it for or do you have a specific license form required for your project such as GPL, LGPL or BSD?

Answer (score 3):

The only open source framework I know(and used) for ETL processing in java is [Spring-Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/) and it's the only implementation(AFAIK) of the `jsr-352`.
 I'm not sure if it suits you because in a simple google search I found some pure ETL frameworks like [CloverETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CloverETL) but  I haven't tried them yet so I can not have an opinion. So far I've been using Spring-Batch for ETL and Batch processing for almost 6 months and I'm quite happy with it :)
Hope I helped a little!

Comment: thank you for answering am letting this question  open for some more suggestion.. +1..

Comment: Spring-Batch is a batch processor. While in theory it can be used to build an ETL tool, it does not add much value, and does not provide components to help with ETL. You should concentrate your answer on CloverETL, which a thousand time more suitable as an ETL framework :-) Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul allow me to disagree,by saying that SB is only a batch processor is like saying that vehicles shouldn't carry objects because they are made to carry people. SB is really popular for ETL processing(that's why I answered) if the user has a basic knowledge of java and a google search can prove that :) . On the other hand I can not focus on CloverETL because I never used it and I do not intend too, I do ETL jobs with SB. To tell you the truth I believe SB is more appropriate than Clover for this question because it's a **JAVA-FRAMEWORK** as the question suggests

Comment: Interesting! Adding this information to the answer would be great :-)

Answer (score 0):

For full transparency, I work for Talend.

Talend has an open source version of our data integration capabilities, called Talend Open Studio. The output of Talend ETL jobs are native code. For traditional systems, this would be Java.

Talend Open Studio has over 3 million download, and a large user community at https://www.talendforge.org/.